# Django query - join on the same table

Tags: django, join

i have a mini blog app, and a 'timeline' . there i want to be displayed all the posts from all the friends of a user, plus the posts of that user himself.
For that, i have to make some kind of a 'join' between the results of two queries (queries on the same table) , so that the final result will be the combination of the user - possessor of the account, and all his friends.
My query looks like this:

```
blog = New.objects.filter(created_by = following,created_by = request.user)
```

By that ',' I wanted to make a 'join' - I found something like this on a doc- but this method is not correct - I'm getting an error.

How else could be done this 'join' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Django `Q` (query parameter) objects to create complex queries with logical operators (`&`, `|`, and `~`).  You can also use `__` (double underscore) to join in query parameters.

```
# is this what you want?
blog = New.objects.filter( Q(created_by__followed_by = request.user)
                          |Q(created_by = request.user) )
```

For more details see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects.